# Execute a remote script on a remote computer via SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a bash script on Machine B which I want to run on Machine B. I am using Machine A right now. Is this possible?

So far I've only managed to do it if the script lives on Machine A using the following command:

```
ssh user@machineb 'bash -s' < /path/machinea/script.sh
```

I don't want to have to copy this remote script locally. Is there a way to run this remote script on a remote machine through my local machine via SSH?

Comment: the same way you run a local script: `./path/myscript`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From `man ssh`:

> If *command* is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

where *command* is the last argument of ssh

Therefore, the only thing you have to do is move the single quote:

```
ssh user@machineb 'bash -s < /path/machinea/script.sh'
```

Basically the command you provided above redirects the machine A script to ssh, which transmits the script through the network and runs it in machine B. Even less hassle to run scripts/commands locally on machine B.

Comment: It didn't work for me with `-s` flag. As the `bash` manual says, it waits for the standard input. I had to exclude `-s` flag to execute remote script.